# How can I make radio buttons work inside a JQuery UI accordion?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I've searched and some people have asked this but nobody's given an adequate answer and most askers didn't provide useful example code.  I pared it down to just the thing that I am trying to do but which does not work.  The accordion works but the radio buttons do not.  Is there any way to make this work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(
        function()
        {
            $('#mystuff').accordion(
            {
                header: "div.hdr",
                collapsible: true,
                heightStyle: "content"
            });
        }
      );
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <div id="mystuff">
        <div class="hdr">
          <span><input type="radio" name="r1" value="A" checked="checked" /></span>
          <span>Choose A</span>
          <span><input type="radio" name="r1" value="B" /></span>
          <span>Choose B</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          This is the body for 1.
        </div>
        <div class="hdr">
          <span><input type="radio" name="r2" value="A" checked="checked" /></span>
          <span>Choose A</span>
          <span><input type="radio" name="r2" value="B" /></span>
          <span>Choose B</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          This is the body for 2.
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: David Thomas's suggestion worked.  Here is the revised example, fixed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(
        function()
        {
            $('#mystuff').accordion(
            {
                header: "div.hdr",
                collapsible: true,
                heightStyle: "content"
            });
            $('input[type=radio],label').on('click',function(e){e.stopPropagation();});
        }
      );
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <div id="mystuff">
        <div class="hdr">
          <span><input id="r1a" type="radio" name="r1" value="A" checked="checked" /></span><label for="r1a">Choose A</label>
          <span><input id="r1b" type="radio" name="r1" value="B" /></span><label for="r1b">Choose B</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          This is the body for 1.
        </div>
        <div class="hdr">
          <span><input id="r2a" type="radio" name="r2" value="A" checked="checked" /></span><label for="r2a">Choose A</label>
          <span><input id="r2b" type="radio" name="r2" value="B" /></span><label for="r2b">Choose B</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          This is the body for 2.
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention: in the code I originally tried to do this in, I had an onclick event handler for the inputs.  I put a breakpoint in that hander in Firebug and when it stopped, the other radio was clicked and stayed that way through my event handler.  I stepped out of it and something in jquery.js switched it back but I couldn't understand what it was.  I think Firebug gets confused in jquery's event handers.  I know I do.

Comment: if you forgot some thing edit your post and add it , you can see the edit option at the bottom of your post

Answer (score 3):

Here's one option:

```
$('div.hdr span').click(function(e){
    // stops the click event bubbling/propagating beyond the span
    e.stopPropagation();
    // finds the previous span,
    // finds the radio input in that span (if there is one)
    // and checks it (though you should use the label element for this, really
    $(this).prev('span').find('input:radio').prop('checked', true);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zxbAe/1/).

Comment: That worked!  I've added a working version of my original example code to the initial post, so that people reading this question later can more easily see how it can be made to work.  I would have voted for your answer, but apparently, I'm not allowed to do that yet.